# Please help me to identify these items?

Tags: ancient-history

My toddler, who likes to collect stones, came across these items during a walk around the outskirts of Norwich, England. The item that looks like the head of a spear is definitely man-made. I'm not sure about the other one. The head of the spear looks like it's been carved a long time ago, judging by how smooth the surface is. Both items are made of stone. What's your opinion on these items?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Definitely man-made"? Why?

Comment: @Joachim To be fair, they do have that 'golden ratio of manmadeness' about them.